# Pop up or message box type page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup

Im not sure what to ask for. But i want to load another smaller page over the top of my default page asking the user to register. I dont want it to be a message box but instead a 400 by 400 window that they can easly close of they do not want to register. What is this called so i can google how to acomplish it. Any tutorials links would be helpfull too.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at jQuery UI and the Dialog module. Very easy to set up, and as it's not a real pop-up window, it's unintrusive (imho)

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: How can you tell that they are looking for a web solution? There are pages in WPF and Silverlight as well.

Comment: A web page is statistically more likely when talking about popups, especially when talking about registering, no?

Comment: Thanks ill check out that link.

Comment: @M.Babcock sure, language is imprecise at the best of times. But what's your point?

Comment: @CsharpBeginner If you feel this is what you want, don't forget to return and mark my response as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @x0n - The language would make a difference on how to answer, and you answered without knowing for sure so I was just curious how you drew your conclusion that they meant web.

Comment: @M.Babcock Well, now you know :)